# How to prove that $\langle U^HTUx , \ x\rangle = \langle Tx ,\ x\rangle$ for $\|x\| = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Assume $ U$ is a unitary matrix and $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $\|x\| = 1$
Prove: $\langle U^HTUx\ , \ x\rangle = \langle Tx\ ,\ x\rangle$

I know that $\langle U^HTUx\ , \ x\rangle = \langle TUx\ ,\ Ux\rangle$ ( the property of the inner product).

And I have a feeling that $(xU)^HT^HUx = x^HTx$ ( because $\|Ux\| = \|x\| = 1$, but I don't know how to prove it strictly.

Can you show me the derivation? Thanks!

---edit:

Is my statement wrong?

I am speaking *Numerical range* :
 $W(T) = \{\langle Tx,x\rangle :x\in\mathbb{C}^n;||x|| =1\} \subseteq\mathbb{C}$
and $ W(U^HTU) = W(T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is no true in fact in $\mathbb{R^2}$ let 
$$
U=\left(\begin{matrix}
i& 0\\
0& -i
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
then $U$ is unitary matrix and 
$$
T=\left(\begin{matrix}
1& 1\\
1& 2
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
we have :
$$
U^tTU=\left(\begin{matrix}
-i& 0\\
0& i
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
1& 1\\
1& 2
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
i& 0\\
0& -i
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
-i& -i\\
i& 2i
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
i& 0\\
0& -i
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1& -1\\
-1& 2
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
the conclusion come directly by [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839427/let-h-be-hilbert-and-t-a-blo-such-that-th-rightarrow-h-prove-that-lan/1839441#1839441) or for $x=(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}) $
we have :
$$
\langle T x,x\rangle=(\sqrt2,\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2})\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)=5/2
$$
but 
$$
\langle U^tTU x,x\rangle=(0,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)=1/2
$$

**Edit : **
For the second question this is true that numerical range is preserved under unitary maps, in fact this use this trivial lemma

> $$\|x\|=1 \iff \|Ux\|=1$$

Proof :
$$
\|Ux\|^2=\langle Ux,Ux\rangle=\langle U^tUx,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle=\|x\|
$$

so 
\begin{eqnarray}
W(U^tTU)&=&\{ \langle U^tTUx,x\rangle ; \|x\|=1\}\\&=&\{ \langle U^tTUx,x\rangle ; \|Ux\|=1\}\\
&=& \{ \langle TUx,Ux\rangle ; \|Ux\|=1\}\\
&=&\{ \langle T\color{red}{y},\color{red}{y}\rangle ; \|\color{red}{y}\|=1\}\\
&=& W(T)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hello! I have edited my question. Is there any mistake in my statement? But the last equation is true

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, take:

- $x = (1, 0)^t$,
- $U$ = clockwise rotation by $90^\circ$,
- $T$ = matrix with $T_{11} = 1$ and zeros elsewhere.

Then $\langle T x, x \rangle \neq \langle U^H T U x, x \rangle$.

The numerical range of $T$ and $U^H T U$ is, of course, the same, because you can set $y = U x$ and loop over $y$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Hello! I have edited my question. Is there any mistake in my statement? But the last equation is true