# If $\langle T(x), x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$, must $T$ must be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T : W \rightarrow W$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional complex inner product space. Suppose that $\langle T(x), x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in W$. Must $T$ must be zero?

I can only prove all eigenvalues of $T$ are zero.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839427/42969.

Comment: This is an interesting question though: if you can prove that all the eigenvalues are zero, i.e. $T$ is nilpotent, try the typical nilpotent nonzero matrix $T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and see what happens.