# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for an Operator to be Zero

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $<,>$ be its norm, and $A:H\to H$ be an operator. Is it true
$A=0 \Leftrightarrow\langle\Psi, A \Psi\rangle=0\ \left(^\forall \Psi\in H\right)$?

Comment: False for real Hilbert spaces, standard fact for complex Hilbert spaces.

Comment: If $A$ is rotation by $\pi/2$ in $\mathbb R^2$, then isn't $\langle v, Av\rangle=0$ for all $v\in \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Doesn't the Related tab give a dupe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576899/langle-tu-u-rangle-0-forall-u-in-e-longrightarrow-t-0 ?

Comment: Thank you for all comments. I know that it is true for complex Hilbert spaces and false for real Hilbert spaces. But I don't find the proof for complex Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I found the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839427/let-h-be-hilbert-and-t-a-blo-such-that-th-rightarrow-h-prove-that-lan?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $H$ be hilbert and $T$ a BLO, such that $T:H\rightarrow H$. Prove that $\langle T(x),x \rangle = 0$ implies $T = 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839427/let-h-be-hilbert-and-t-a-blo-such-that-th-rightarrow-h-prove-that-lan)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem:Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $<,>$ be its inner product, and $A$ be an operator.
If $<x,Ax>=0$ (for any $x\in H$), then $A=0$.

Proof: For any $x,y\in H$,
$<x+y,T(x+y)>=<x,Tx>+<x,Ty>+<y,Tx>+<y,Ty>$
$=<x,Ty>+<y,Tx>$.

By the assumption, $<x,Ty>+<y,Tx>=0$.

We replace $x$ by $ix$ and get

$-i<x,Ty>+i<y,Tx>=0$

By the two equation, we get

$<x, Ty>=0$.

We substitute $x=Ty$ and get $||Ty||^2=0$. It means $Ty=0$ for any $y\in H$.